# Texmaker on Mac touchpad

Tags: texmaker

Whenever I slightly touch the touchpad on my Mac Texmaker chooses to "unfocus" the cursor so I cannot write. Then I need to click the text window again to keep writing. I have tried to find out how to stop this from happening, but I can not find the place to fix this in the options. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Are you sure this is a TeXmaker problem and not a Mac problem? Does it only happen with TeXmaker, and not other editors?

Comment: Thank you. It does not happen in other text editors, such as TextEdit - but I have not tried other Latex editors. For example, if I scroll up or down in the preview window on the right, it un-focuses my cursor in the editor window on the left so I can not write.

Comment: You may want to try a native Mac TeX editor. I highly recommend TeXShop.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will give that a shot.